# Content url security at browser end

Tags: javascript, java, algorithm

We have implemented TEA algo for encryption and decrytion of our content api .
So if the client hits our REST api he will get the ecncrypted data. And at the front end the player will decrypt it after getting key from an api.

Question is  , that the player will open at the brwoser / client end , if the player can get the key so the attacker can get the key .

What design will help to achieve our goal which is making our content urls secured , knowing there is no DRM services we are using and we cannot use https.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you're more or less trying to reimplement HTTPS or TLS over HTTP. It is a *bad idea* and won't end well.

Just use HTTPS. I can't think of any reason why you could not use it in 2017 on the general web. That will get you security for the communication channel (people can't intercept what you're communicating), but also trust that you're speaking with the right server (people can't pose as you or MitM you etc.).

It's unclear what the goals of this are? Is it to prevent people from seeing the data for the player? Or to only allow some users to see it and not others?

Comment: ultimate goal is that no one can get the url and download data.. but the player should be able to play it. the player we are using is the JW player at the client side application , requesting data over REST api.

Comment: HTTPS will also ensure that the URLs accessed by the browser aren't visible to third parties - just the client and the server. However, you can see the URLs you are accessing from the browser, so it won't help to hide your URLs in general, just what URLs a particular session accesses. There's some extra work you need to do in order to achieve something like that (per session urls perhaps?), but a determined adversary will be able to intercept this as well. In the end, the URL needs to be accessed externally.